# Is all the articulation point of a graph are always connected?

Tags: onionkit

Is all the articulation point of a graph(directed or undirected) are always connected after removing all non-articulation point from the graph ?
[image: from geeksforgeeks.org]

Answer (score 1):

No, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR3jW.png) is a counter example using an undirected graph.

Articulation points are 3 and 4, which aren't connected when removing all other points.